# Modeling data in couchbase

Tags: .net, nosql, couchbase, data-modeling

We are trying to use Couchbase as the back end for for an API.. And the Api URL is something like this..

http://someserver/{Product}/{Id}

Where product and Id will change with every request.

Every product will have its own set of data and the same holds good for different id's

My first thought was to have a document for every product and id, which means

Doc 1:- product-1
Doc2:- product-2 and so on ..

Doc n:- id-1
Doc n+1:- id-2

But when we relooked at the business problem we can have 6 possible values for product and 1000+ values for Id which will soon grow in to lot. With the above approach we will end up having lot of docs.

And every Id will have a product associated with it.which means for every id  there are 6 possible products as of now.

So can anybody suggest the effective way of modeling this data.

Comment: Will one ID have only a single product associated with it, or could one ID associate to multiple products (both now and in the future)?

Comment: When I say ID in business terms they are actually partners and every partner has multiple products. So when an API request comes in with this URL   /Energy/100  all API has to do it fetch data for Partner 100 and its product being energy

Answer (score 1):

As I see it having lots of documents might consume space, but unless you contain product data directly in each *ID* doc, I don't think there are many other practical ways of modelling. In terms of drawbacks of having lots of docs, there will obviously be a storage cost (but this shouldn't really exceed any other model, as you'll still have the same amount of data to store, however you model it, and other ways besides lots of discrete docs could result in duplicate data), as well as consideration required if using views on the bucket.

Providing you have sufficient storage (and memory, for the set of active data you'll typically require), and take care with your use of views, I can't think of a standout way of modelling the data. Lots of docs may seem inefficient, but it makes logical sense from a structural perspective. About the only hard and fast piece of advice would be to make sure that the references the *Product* doc uses for each *id* (or vice versa) reference the key for that document (i.e., the *document uid*) rather than some more human-readable field of the document being referenced (although, providing the value is unique, such a field could be used as (part of) the document uid.

---

An example document would be (e.g. `product::abc`):

```
{
    "id" = "product::abc",
    "name" = "abc",
    "type" = "xyz",
    "partners" = [
        "partner::abc", "partner::def", ..., "partney::xyz"
    ]
}
```

And then for `partner::abc`:

```
{
    "id" = "partner::abc",
    "name" = "abc",
    "location" = "xyz"
}
```